# File not visible in Drive after API upload and inserting permissions using php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm crowbarring the google api into a laravel app.

The file appears to upload correctly but remains invisible in the Drive GUI.

Many searches later and I've got this code to set the permissions of the newly created file:

```
$id = id of created file
$value = 'my@email.address.com';
$type = "anyone";
$role = "writer";
$drive->insertPermission($id, $value, $type, $role);  

function insertPermission($fileId, $value, $type, $role) {

      $service = $this->service;
      $newPermission = new \Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
      $newPermission->setType($type);
      $newPermission->setRole($role);

      try {
        return $service->permissions->create($fileId, $newPermission);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      }
      return NULL;
    }
```

This seems to work. No errors are thrown. But I still can't see the file when I search in my drive. Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing $type="anyone"; to $type="user"; and $role="writer"; to $role="reader";

Comment: Are you sure that the account you're looking in is the same account you uploaded to?

Comment: @pinoyyid I created a service account so I'm assuming thats the account the files are uploading too, then I need to share them with my primary account.

Comment: @Pushpendra I've given that a quick go, but no dice. I'll keep trying down those lines though.

Comment: that sounds like that's the problem. Service Accounts are totally separate from the user Account that you used to create them. You can either share the folder (ugly imho) or use the intended account directly.

Comment: @pinoyyid Thank you for helping with this. I ended up with this:

`$newPermission = new \Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
      $newPermission->setType('user');
      $newPermission->setRole('reader');
      $newPermission->setEmailAddress('my@emailaddress');`

Its now uploading the file and sharing it with the primary account. I get a notification and the file is visible in the "shared with me" section.

Do you know if I can use my primary email address for the api? I'm currently using a _gserviceaccount.com_ changing that to my primary email doesnt seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pushpendra pointed out I need to change

```
$type="anyone"; to $type="user"; 
and 
$role="writer"; to $role="reader";
```

Also - in the end I solved this by creating a folder in the drive UI and sharing that folder with the service account. The service account is able to create/update files in that shared folder and I get a notification when it does so.